# Contract function cannot be executed

Tags: solidity

I wrote a contract for token and token sale by following a few tutorials.
Contracts are deploying fine, tokens are created and functional.
However I cannot execute a couple of functions in both of those contracts.
Here is token contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 * @notice https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
 */
library SafeMath {
    /**
     * SafeMath mul function
     * @dev function for safe multiply, throws on overflow.
     **/
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * SafeMath div funciotn
     * @dev function for safe devide, throws on overflow.
     **/
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * SafeMath sub function
     * @dev function for safe subtraction, throws on overflow.
     **/
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    /**
     * SafeMath add function
     * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances.
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  uint256 totalSupply_;

  /**
  * @dev total number of tokens in existence
  */
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
  }

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Increase the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _addedValue The amount of tokens to increase the allowance by.
   */
  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = (
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue));
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Decrease the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To decrement
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _subtractedValue The amount of tokens to decrease the allowance by.
   */
  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];

    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }

    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  event OwnershipRenounced(address indexed previousOwner);
  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  /**
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to relinquish control of the contract.
   */
  function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
    emit OwnershipRenounced(owner);
    owner = address(0);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Pausable
 * @dev Base contract which allows children to implement an emergency stop mechanism.
 */
contract Pausable is Ownable {
  event Pause();
  event Unpause();

  bool public paused = false;

  /**
   * @dev Modifier to make a function callable only when the contract is not paused.
   */
  modifier whenNotPaused() {
    require(!paused || msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Modifier to make a function callable only when the contract is paused.
   */
  modifier whenPaused() {
    require(paused);
    _;
  }

  /**
     * @dev called by the owner to pause, triggers stopped state
     **/
    function _pause() public onlyOwner {
        require(!paused);
        paused = true;
        emit Pause();
    }

  /**
   * @dev called by the owner to unpause, returns to normal state
   */
  function _unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
    require(paused == true);
    paused = false;
    emit Unpause();
  }
}

/**
 * @title Pausable token
 * @dev StandardToken modified with pausable transfers.
 **/
contract MyTestToken is StandardToken, Pausable {
    string public name;// = "My Test Token";
    string public symbol;// = "MYTT";
    uint256 public decimals;// = 8;
    uint256 public initial_supply;// = 100000000000;//

    bool public isPauseOn = false;

    modifier ifNotPaused(){
      require(!isPauseOn || msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }

    function _doPause() public{
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      isPauseOn = true;
    }

    function _doUnpause() public{
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      isPauseOn = false;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfer tokens when not paused
     **/
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public ifNotPaused returns (bool) {
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev transferFrom function to tansfer tokens when token is not paused
     **/
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public ifNotPaused returns (bool) {
        return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev approve spender when not paused
     **/
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public ifNotPaused returns (bool) {
        return super.approve(_spender, _value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev increaseApproval of spender when not paused
     **/
    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public ifNotPaused returns (bool success) {
        return super.increaseApproval(_spender, _addedValue);
    }

    /**
     * @dev decreaseApproval of spender when not paused
     **/
    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public ifNotPaused returns (bool success) {
        return super.decreaseApproval(_spender, _subtractedValue);
    }


    // Mint more tokens
    function _mint(uint mint_amt) public onlyOwner{
        totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.add(mint_amt);
        balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(mint_amt);
    }

    /**
   * Pausable Token Constructor
   * @dev Create and issue tokens to msg.sender.
   */
  constructor() public {
    name = "My Test Token";
    symbol = "MYTT";
    decimals = 8;
    initial_supply = 10000000000000000000;

    totalSupply_ = initial_supply;
    balances[msg.sender] = initial_supply;
  }
}
```

And here is Sale contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external returns (uint);
}

contract TokenSale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public price;
    uint public dynamicLocktime;
    uint public globalLocktime;
    uint public lockType = 0;
    token public tokenReward;
    uint public exchangeRate;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => uint256) public tokenBalanceOf;
    mapping(address => uint256) public timelocksOf;

    address[] public founders;
    address public owner;

    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, uint exchangeRate, uint token, uint time, uint timelock, bool isContribution);
    event IsCharged(bool isCharged);
    event TokensClaimed(address founder, uint tokens);
    event TransferOwnership();
    event ChangeExchangeRate(uint oldExchangeRate, uint newExchangeRate);
    event NewGlobalLocktime(uint timelockUntil);
    event NewDynamicLocktime(uint timelockUntil);
    uint public tokenAvailable = 0;
    bool public charged = false;


    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    constructor(
        address _beneficiary,
        address _addressOfTokenUsedAsReward,
        uint _globalLocktime,
        uint _dynamicLocktime,
        uint _exchangeRate
    ) public {
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        dynamicLocktime = _dynamicLocktime;
        tokenReward = token(_addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
        globalLocktime = now + _globalLocktime * 1 minutes;
        exchangeRate = _exchangeRate;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable public {
          require(charged);
          require(msg.value >= 10000000000); 
          uint am = (msg.value* exchangeRate * 100000000)/(1 ether); 
          require( tokenAvailable >= am);
          uint amount = msg.value;
          balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
          amountRaised += amount;
          tokenBalanceOf[msg.sender] += am;
          tokenAvailable -= am;

          if(timelocksOf[msg.sender] == 0){
            timelocksOf[msg.sender] = now + dynamicLocktime * 1 minutes;
          }

          emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, exchangeRate, am, now, timelocksOf[msg.sender], true);
          founders.push(msg.sender);
    }


    modifier onlyOwner(){
      require(msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == beneficiary);
      _;
    }


    function doChargeCrowdsale() public onlyOwner{
      tokenAvailable = tokenReward.balanceOf(this);
      if(tokenAvailable > 0){
        charged = true;
        emit IsCharged(charged);
      }
    }



    function claimTokens(address adr) public{
      require(tokenBalanceOf[adr] > 0);

      if(lockType == 0){ // lock by address
        require(now >= timelocksOf[adr]);
      }else if(lockType == 1){ // global lock
        require(now >= globalLocktime);
      } // else there is no lock

      if(tokenReward.transfer(adr, tokenBalanceOf[adr])){
        emit TokensClaimed(adr, tokenBalanceOf[adr]);
        tokenBalanceOf[adr] = 0;
        balanceOf[adr] = 0;
      }
    }



    function transferRaisedFunds() public onlyOwner {
        if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
           emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, exchangeRate, 0, now, 0, false);
        }
    }



    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner{
      owner = newOwner;
      emit TransferOwnership();
    }


    function setExchangeRate(uint newExchangeRate) public onlyOwner{
      emit ChangeExchangeRate(exchangeRate, newExchangeRate);
      exchangeRate = newExchangeRate;
    }


    function setGlobalLocktime(uint mins) public onlyOwner{
      globalLocktime = now + mins * 1 minutes;
      emit NewGlobalLocktime(globalLocktime);
    }


    function setDynamicLocktime(uint mins) public onlyOwner{
      dynamicLocktime = now + mins * 1 minutes;
      emit NewDynamicLocktime(dynamicLocktime);
    }


    function setLockType(uint newType) public onlyOwner{
        require(newType == 0 || newType == 1 || newType == 2);
        lockType = newType;
    }


    function unlockTokensFor(address adr) public onlyOwner{
      timelocksOf[adr] = 1;
    }


    function resetLockFor(address adr) public onlyOwner{
      timelocksOf[adr] = 0;
    }


    function getLeftOver() public onlyOwner{
      if(tokenReward.transfer(beneficiary, tokenAvailable)){
        emit TokensClaimed(beneficiary, tokenAvailable);
        tokenAvailable = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

The functions that cannot be executed are : `doChargeCrowdsale` (Sale Contract), `_doPause` (Token contract)
This is what I see when I try to execute one of the functions.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea why these function do not work?

EDIT : The problem functions :

```
// in token contract
function _doPause() public{
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      isPauseOn = true;
    }


// in sale contract
function doChargeCrowdsale() public onlyOwner{
      tokenAvailable = tokenReward.balanceOf(this);
      if(tokenAvailable > 0){
        charged = true;
        emit IsCharged(charged);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can call these functions only with the account which you have used for deploying the contracts. Can you first verify that you are not trying to call them with any other account?

Comment: yes, I have checked that I use same account I deployed my contracts with.

Comment: Side note: when a function-call fails, the first thing for you to check is any `require`, `assert` or `revert` operation in the function. Clearly, the only such operation in both of these function is `require(msg.sender == owner)` (in the first case, it is embedded within the `onlyOwner` modifier).

Comment: Function `_doPause` can fail only because of that. Function `tokenReward` can fail either because of that, or because `tokenReward` is not initialized correctly. This, in addition to "out of gas" or not enough funds in the calling account of course, but that's true for any function in your code which is not `pure` or `view` (and you say that all the other functions complete successfully).

Comment: I actually deployed those same contracts on ESN(ethersocial which is a fork from Ethereum project) main/testnet and these functions worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, though I do not how exactly it fixes the problem, however here is the solution :

```
uint something = 0; // just init a uint

// in token contract
function _doPause(uint someUint) public{
      something = someUint;
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      isPauseOn = true;
    }


// in sale contract
function doChargeCrowdsale(uint someUint) public onlyOwner{
      something = someUint;
      tokenAvailable = tokenReward.balanceOf(this);
      if(tokenAvailable > 0){
        charged = true;
        emit IsCharged(charged);
      }
    }
```

So I've just added an argument to be passed to functions that doesn't change any logic nor does it do anything at all. but with only this changes the functions can be executed without errors.

If anyone can explain or shed some light on this behavior please do so.